# How to select and deselect the thumbnail images and selected image store in array in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to i phone programming.I have create custom button inside that i am attaching images for each and every custom button.Now that custom button images is displaying in thumbnail.Now what i want if i select any thumbnail image or custom button.Here i want to select and deselect that thumbnail images  and I want to store that selected images tag value in array.How to do this Below one my code.Using below code i am creating custom button and attaching image to custom button.

```
blaukypath =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (NSString* path in array)
   {
 [blaukypath addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
 NSLog(@"%@",path);
   }
  myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 840.0)];
  myScrollView.delegate = self;
  myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 840.0);
  myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

  float horizontal = 8.0;
  float vertical = 8.0;
  for(int i=0; i<[blaukypath count]; i++)
  {
   if((i%4) == 0 && i!=0)
   {
   horizontal = 8.0;
   vertical = vertical + 70.0 + 8.0;
   }

                    buttonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    [buttonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(horizontal, vertical, 70.0, 70.0)];
                    [buttonImage setTag:i];

                    [buttonImage setImage:[blaukypath objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [buttonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [myScrollView addSubview:buttonImage];

                    horizontal = horizontal + 70.0 + 8.0;
                }

                [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, vertical + 78.0)];


                [self.myScrollView addSubview:buttonImage];
```

Now if select any thumbnail image i want to select and deselect the thumbnail images and selected thumbnail images i want to store in array.

```
-(void)buttonImagePressed:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    if (btn.tag==0)
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag=1;
    }
    else{
        [btn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag=0;
    }
```

some body told that by using above code i will work for but i not working Exactly what i want.i want to select and deselect and also selected images i want to store in array.
Thanks
Aslam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the images for button asper the `UIControlState`

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tapCollection;

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonBackGround.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Selected.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

-(void)viewDidLoad{

   self.tapCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)buttonImagePressed:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

  //If checked, uncheck and visa versa
  [selectedButton setSelected:![selectedButton isSelected]];

  if([selectedButton isSelected])
  {
      [self.tapCollection addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:btn.tag]];
  }
  else
  {
     //remove btn.tag from self.tapCollection
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving replay.its working..can u please tell me how can i store seleted tag button value inside array